# Чи вважається слово "скидка" запозиченням з російської для поняття "знижка"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми, розмовна-українська, віддієслівні-іменники

СУМ потверджує, що слово *"скидка"* розмовне і означає *знижка*, тоді коли слово *"скидати"* у значенні "зменшувати на певну кількість" такої позначки немає, а отже може вживатися не лише у розмовному стилі.

Чи може слово *"скидка"* рівноцінно вживатися замість слова "знижка" у рекламі та на вітринах крамниць?

Comment: "Скидка" в значення "знижка" є просто калькою з російської. Навіть для розмовної української, особисто мені, звучить досить дивно та ріже вуха. А стосовно реклами чи вітринах, то, безумовно, тільки один варіант прийнятний - "знижка"